# Tamagochi Selection | Python 3.0 | Begginer

Tags: python-3.x, function

Well, I'm trying to make an initial tamagochi selection (ignore the names, just testing), but I doesn't work.

When I type 2 or 3 or any other name than Rattatouie, I get: "Rattatouie é o seu novo Tamagochi!". In English it would be "Rattatouie is your new Tamagochi!" (I'm brazilian)

```
def pick_tamagochi():
    print('*'*20,"Tamagochi 2018",20*'*')
    print('1 - Rattatouie')
    print('2 - Rabbitack')
    print('3 - Sonic Hedgehog')
    TamagochiSelect = input('>>> Escolha seu Tamagochi:')

    if TamagochiSelect == '1' or 'Rattatouie':
        TamagochiSelect = 'Rattaouie'
        print('Rattatouie é o seu novo Tamagochi!')
    elif TamagochiSelect == '2' or 'Rabbitack':
        TamagochiSelect = 'Rabbitack'
        print('Rabbitack é o seu novo Tamagochi! ')
    elif TamagochiSelect == '3' or 'Sonic Hedgehog':
        TamagochiSelect = 'Sonic'
        print('Sonic é o seu novo Tamagochi!')
    else: 
        print('Nome não compatível')

print(pick_tamagochi())
```

Does anyone knows how I can solve it?

Comment: You might wanna consider to check out how Python operators work. For example at the following page: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp ─ This is just a suggestion. Any Python tutorial will probably contain at least one example about how to use operators (https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tutorial+english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `in` operator to test for multiple values:

```
if TamagochiSelect in ('1', 'Rattatouie'):
```

Otherwise `TamagochiSelect == '1' or 'Rattatouie'` simply means to test if `TamagochiSelect` is equal to `'1'` or if `'Rattatouie'` is `True`, which `'Rattatouie'` always is (because it is a non-empty string).

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional should be written as:

```
if TamagochiSelect == '1' or TamagochiSelect == 'Rattatouie':
```

Otherwise Python will interpret it as `(if TamagochiSelect == '1') or (TamagochiSelect)` and non-empty strings evaluate to `True` (you can verify it by typing `bool('some string')` and `bool('')`)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your boolean operator(OR) is not placed correctly, it check on the left side and sees

```
TamagochiSelect == '1'
```

this returns False but on the right it sees

```
'Rattatouie'
```

which is always True . A solution would be

```
if TamagochiSelect == '1' or TamagochiSelect == 'Rattatouie':
```